# How much energy could we harvest from a 0.1V source (gedankenexperiment)

Tags: power, power-electronics, theory

For the sake of a thought experiment, suppose two 10-metre balls appear magically somewhere on land. In the middle of the Sahara desert for example.

The balls are the terminals of a perfect voltage source at 0.1V potential. There's no internal resistance. If you managed to connect a 1 milliohm resistance across them, you'd get 100 amps through it.

Let's also assume the balls are made from some magical indestructible, unmeltable metal, that is also superconducting up to thousands of degrees.
The distance between the balls is also 10 metres, and let's say they are unmovable.

How much power could we realistically harvest from such an unlimited power source, and how?

Comment: How much power could we realistically harvest from an unrealistic power source? Odd question. But you need to define "harvest": Does converting the power to heat count as harvesting?

Comment: I know nothing of power generation and transmission, but I believe "free" energy at the sahara desert would be at some point more expensive than "relatively cheap" energy close to power consuming centres (cities, industries, etc)

Comment: Unmovable balls relative to earth, sun, solar system, galaxy, etc...  DC or AC??

Comment: That's not even a twist, 10mV and 1000 miles between them would be a twist. The LTC3108 can harvest energy from voltages as low as 20mV. I would however turn the energy into heat for a turbine or make a electro-mechanical device (for example a motor) that drives a generator.

Comment: 10W? Not worth going to the Sahara desert for. A few solar panels could produce 100 times more 'unlimited' power, without the hassle of having to boost the voltage.

Comment: I see.. if you crowbar your supply with a superconductor do you get infinite amps

Comment: Build a superconducting rod to connect the two balls to test and see if your god can maintain a perfect voltage source across a perfect superconductor with perfectly infinite current.

Comment: Real-world superconductors have a certain maximum current that they can support before losing superconductivity.  I think this means that they are not the best thing to use with this hypothetical source - a (large, cooled) regular conductor can support more current.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this question - it has the potential to prompt a number of interesting and educational theoretical discussions.  I suppose you could make the case that it's better suited to worldbuilding.se, but I feel like the author is asking it to better understand electrical theory rather than looking for a fantasy plot element.

Comment: Energy is harvested (as per your title) not power (as per your words). Given the contradictory nature of your question and the superfluous detail andspoof factor I vote to close.

Comment: @pericynthion - "theoretical discussions" are pretty much by definition off-topic on this site. From the [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the source has zero output impedance, you want to present as low as possible of a load impedance to transfer maximum power.

I would suggest a very fat (10m or more diameter) copper conductor, mechanically clamped to the source terminals, and riddled with drilled holes through which a working fluid such as supercritical steam is passed. You pump the fluid sufficiently fast to keep the temperature of the copper​ below it's melting point (cooler than that, so it doesn't go too soft).  Run the output into a turbine.

You may want to plate the contact points with silver, and perhaps line the heat exchanger channels with something to prevent corrosion. This should be a solved problem in nuclear reactor design.

To put an approximate limit on the power that can be extracted, suppose the terminals are connected with a 10 meter diameter cylinder of solid, pure copper.  By Pouillet's law the resistance of this conductor is about 2 nanoohms.  \$ P=\frac{V^2}{R} \$ then gives **5 megawatts of thermal power** - not very impressive.  Maybe you can get the resistance down a bit by embedding the terminals in a considerably larger conductor, but that won't help more than one order of magnitude at best, and that's not even accounting for the volume taken up by cooling channels.

Real-world superconductors wouldn't be useful here because even a very large, absurdly expensive superconductor will have a critical current lower than that of our big chunk of copper.

Overall I think the scientists' and engineers' efforts would be better spent trying to figure out the new physics implied by these mysterious balls rather than trying to extract a paltry few megawatts from them.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of boiling water and driving a steam turbine in the very same manner. Your answer confirms that this could be the best option for electricity generation.
I guess the god's gift would have been much more useful if you could chop pieces of the terminals and they retained their voltage potential individually. That could be used to make millions of small cells for low power devices, e.g. hearing aids, where no battery replacement is ever needed; or you could make perfect 0.1V voltage references, e.g. in 0805 form factor.